# How would I get preload to be called after my button listener has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I have an html5 application that I have been working on. In the app, I want the j5 audio library to run AFTER the user has uploaded a file from their computer (because I want to use it to visualize the amplitudes on a canvas).  However, I am confused about how I would go about solving this problem.

I need to import the item prior to preload, but the upload occurs only after the user has clicked the upload button. How can I understand this asynchronous problem?

```js
var test, song, path, audio;
    function preload(){
      song = loadSound();
    }
    
    function setup(){
      createCanvas(200, 200);
    }
    
    function draw(){
      background(0);
    }
    
    document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      if (e.target.files.length) {
        path = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
        audio = new Audio(path);
        
        //HERE is where setup, etc show occur.
        //Create Canvas, etcetc
      }
    });
```

```html
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Mju</title>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
    
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <h3>Upload Song:  <input onclick="this.style.display='none';" id="song" type="file" accept="audio/*"></h3>
      </body>
```

General structure of code: Take file from **input** -> preprocess the song so it is playable prior to the canvas loading. To run the code yourself: https://repl.it/@JacksonEnnis/Mju

### Note

Interestingly enough, a previous attempt at the project I am doing has allowed me to succeed in doing this. But I cannot figure out how these two projects are different in a significant way: https://repl.it/@JacksonEnnis/MusicJournal

Comment: Have you used [`successCallback`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile) in `loadSound()`?

Comment: I've tried "song = loadSound(path, console.log("OOF, Didn't load in time"), preload());" to ensure preloading before, but that sticks me with no shown errors, but stuck in loading... purgatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage `async/await` and promisify the callback API of `p5.SoundFile()`.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("audio-form");
const input = document.getElementById("audio-file");

form.addEventListener("submit", async e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Make ObjectURL
  const path = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);

  // Promisify the callback function
  const sound = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    new p5.SoundFile(path, s => resolve(s), err => reject(err));
  });

  // Do stuff with sound
  console.log(sound);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>

<form id="audio-form">
  <input type="file" id="audio-file" />
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Load audio</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax and `FormData` to submit your file and jquery with the `.change()` method to start the upload when the user has selected the file, then if the upload success, you can setup your audio library.